# Parsing JSON using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON as follows

```
{
  columns      : [RULE_ID,COUNTRY_CODE],
  RULE_ID      : [1,2,3,7,9,101,102,103,104,105,106,4,5,100,30], 
  COUNTRY_CODE : [US,US,CA,US,FR,GB,GB,UM,AF,AF,AL,CA,US,US,US]
}
```

I need to retrive the column names from the columns entry and then use it to search the rest of the entries using jquery.
For example I get each column using

```
jQuery.each(data.columns, function(i,column))
```

I need to loop throgh the rest of the entries using the values I get from the previous loop. ie **without hardcoding COUNTRY_CODE or RULE_ID**.
What is the best way to do that using Jquery?

Comment: nitpicking: this is a JavaScript object, but it's not JSON (the string-based data interchange format)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
jQuery.each(data.columns, function(i,column) {
    jQuery.each(data[column], function(i, row) {
    ....
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Some comments:

Paolo is right, you can use data[column] to get the list of values:

```
jQuery.each(data.columns, function(iCol,column) {
    jQuery.each(data[column], function(iRow, row) {
    ....
    });
});
```

Do you need the columns information ? You could get the list of "columns" by iterating directly over data:

```
for( var column in data )
{
    jQuery.each(data[column], function(i, row) {
    ....
    });
}
```

Not really a question but your JSON is not valid JSON, I hope this was only an example and not your real data:

```
{
  "columns"      : ["RULE_ID","COUNTRY_CODE"],
  "RULE_ID"      : [1,2,3,7,9,101,102,103,104,105,106,4,5,100,30], 
  "COUNTRY_CODE" : ["US","US","CA","US","FR","GB","GB","UM","AF","AF","AL","CA","US","US","US"]
}
```